# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overload-resolution, createobjecturl

hey guys hope you are doing fine . I am new in react js and i am facing some difficulties to fix this error . TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed. I will show you my code . I hope that someone can help me to fix it . Thank you in advance

```js
<Box display="flex" flexWrap="true">
              {this.state.images.map((item, index) => (
                <Box margin="12px">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={this.renderImageUrl(item)}
                    style={{
                      height: "90px",
                      width:
                        this.state.view_type === 0
                          ? "160px"
                          : this.state.view_type === 1
                          ? "210px"
                          : 0,
                      objectFit: "scale-down",
                      backgroundColor: this.state.colors[index],
                    }}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <input
                    id={"contained-button-" + index}
                    type="color"
                    hidden
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      let colors = this.state.colors;
                      colors[index] = e.target.value;
                      this.setState({
                        colors,
                      });
                    }}
                    defaultValue="#000000"
                  />

                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="delete"
                    onClick={(e) => this.removeImage(index)}
                  >
                    <Delete />
                  </IconButton>

                  <label htmlFor={"contained-button-" + index}>
                    <IconButton
                      color="primary"
                      aria-label="upload picture"
                      component="span"
                    >
                      <FormatColorFill />
                    </IconButton>
                  </label>
                </Box>
              ))}
            </Box>
```

and this is the method that i am using :

```js
renderImageUrl = (item) => {
    return URL.createObjectURL(item);
  };
```

when i put the method like that :

```js
 renderImageUrl = (item) => {
    try {
      return URL.createObjectURL(item);
    } catch (error) {
      return item;
    }
  };
```

so the result will be this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4w1.png)

Comment: What is `item`?

Comment: item is the parameter of the image link . I am getting the images from firestore

Comment: So is it a `Blob`, `File` or `MediaSource`?

Comment: item is of type object . I tried to convert it to blob , but I did not know how to convert it correctly